# Check how many numpy array within a numpy array are equal to other numpy arrays within another numpy array of different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**My problem**

Suppose I have

```
a = np.array([ np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4]), np.array([5,6]), np.array([7,8]), np.array([9,10])])
b = np.array([ np.array([5,6]), np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,192])])
```

They are two arrays, of different sizes, containing other arrays (the inner arrays have same sizes!)

I want to count how many items of b (i.e. inner arrays) are also in a. Notice that I am not considering their position!

How can I do that?

**My Try**

```
count = 0
for bitem in b:
     for aitem in a:
         if aitem==bitem:
               count+=1
```

Is there a better way? Especially in one line, maybe with some comprehension..

Comment: Got to upvote for the title alone

Comment: @thanks man, appreciate that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package contains efficient (nlogn, generally) and vectorized solutions to these types of problems:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
count = len(npi.intersection(a, b))
```

Note that this is subtly different than your double loop, discarding duplicate entries in a and b for instance. If you want to retain duplicates in b, this would work:

```
count = npi.in_(b, a).sum()
```

Duplicate entries in a could also be handled by doing npi.count(a) and factoring in the result of that; but anyway, im just rambling on for illustration purposes since I imagine the distinction probably does not matter to you.

Comment: Do you think these two solutions are faster than the ones described above?

Comment: Those methods are quadratic in both memory and computation; so for anything more than a few array elements, definitely

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
a = np.array([ np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4]), np.array([5,6]), np.array([7,8]), np.array([9,10])])
b = np.array([ np.array([5,6]), np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,192])])

count = np.count_nonzero(
    np.any(np.all(a[:, np.newaxis, :] == b[np.newaxis, :, :], axis=-1), axis=0))

print(count)
>>> 2
```

Comment: First, shouldn't `count` be 2?  There's only 2 matching arrays in the input.  You're counting matching elements (5, 6, 1, 2, and 3) instead of matching arrays ((5,6) and (1,2))

Comment: Also, `np.logical_or.reduce(.., axis = 0)` is equivalent to `np.any( . . ., axis = 0)`, and using `np.count_nonzero` on a boolean array is wasteful compared to a simple `sum()`

Comment: @DanielF You're right, I misread the question, I thought it was about common elements in general, not subarrays. `count_nonzero` is significantly faster that `sum` here, though (check `%timeit (np.random.rand(10000000) > .5).sum()` and `%timeit np.count_nonzero(np.random.rand(10000000) > .5)` in IPython).

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want in one liner as follows:

```
count = sum([np.array_equal(x,y) for x,y in product(a,b)])
```

### Explanation

Here's an explanation of what's happening:

1. Iterate through the two arrays using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) which will create an iterator over the cartesian product of the two arrays.
2. Compare each two arrays in a tuple (x,y) coming from step `1.` using [np.array_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)
3. True is equal to 1 when using sum on a list

### Full example:

The final code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 
from itertools import product 
a = np.array([ np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4]), np.array([5,6]), np.array([7,8]), np.array([9,10])])
b = np.array([ np.array([5,6]), np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,192])])
count = sum([np.array_equal(x,y) for x,y in product(a,b)])
# output: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the rows to `dtype = np.void` and then use `np.in1d` as on the resulting 1d arrays

```
def void_arr(a):
    return np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))) 

b[np.in1d(void_arr(b), void_arr(a))]

array([[5, 6],
       [1, 2]])
```

If you just want the number of intersections, it's

```
np.in1d(void_arr(b), void_arr(a)).sum()

2
```

**Note:** if there are repeat items in `b` or `a`, then `np.in1d(void_arr(b), void_arr(a)).sum()` likely won't be equal to `np.in1d(void_arr(a), void_arr(b)).sum()`.  I've reversed the order from my original answer to match your question (i.e. how many elements of `b` are in `a`?)

For more information, see the third answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)