# Sum up indentical list elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with elements, and I want to sum up the accuracy. I want to sum the arrays that have the elements in the same order. I rather not be writing a for loop going through each element with `zip` and summing them up, is there an easier way to do this?

The two arrays are as follows, and currently my code is below for calculating the sum.

```
yp = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
y = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

sums = np.sum(yp == y)
```

I am getting an accuracy of zero.

Comment: `yp` and `y` are python lists. Therefore yp == y returns True (since they are identical). If you want to compute the sum, convert them to numpy array before. `yp = np.array(yp)`

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I will convert them to numpy and see what happens.

Comment: both lists are the same here?

Comment: @eagle Both list are the same size.

Comment: This is a very long list. This Is just the first part. They are not always identical. They just have the same size.

Comment: Converting them to numpy array and then doing `yp == y` will produce you an array of the same size than y and yp, full of boolean. It is a element-wise comparison. If you sum it, it will gives you how many items are identicals.

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(np.equal(y, yp))` should work.

Comment: which is exactly what `np.sum(yp == y)` is doing if `yp` and `y` are numpy arrays ;)

Comment: @AdrienLogut the point is that `np.equal` also works with lists, etc. Also, `np.count_nonzero` should be a bit faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check how many elements are equal in two numpy arrays python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490641/check-how-many-elements-are-equal-in-two-numpy-arrays-python)

Comment: Good point @PaulPanzer !

Comment: `np.sum` does not work for this when both arrays are numpy arrays. I just tried it.

Comment: It definitly does, I've just tested it. Try Paul Panzer solution though.

Comment: Guys I am going to use `zip` Sometimes I get 0 accuracy, sometimes I get 100%. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```
yp = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
y = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

# First make the two arrays in question numpy arrays.
yp = np.array(yp)
y = np.array(y)
array_length = y.shape[1] # store length of sub arrays

equal_elements = np.array(yp) == np.array(y)  # check all equal elements
sums = np.sum(equal_elements, 1) # sum the number of equal elements in each sub array, use axis 1 as each array/sample is axis 0
equal_arrays = np.where(sums==array_length)[0] # returns a tuple, so index first element immediately

number_equal_arrays = equal_arrays.shape[0]  # What elements are equal
print('Number of equal arrays %d' % number_equal_arrays)
print('Accuracy %0.2f' % (number_equal_arrays/yp.shape[0]))
```

prints

> Number of equal arrays 6
>
> Accuracy 1.00